# calling a sip phone

Tags: voip, sip, asterisk

im searching for a simple method to "ping" a sip:user@ip and get back a status like "available for call" , "busy" , "not connected" if the first two require to make his phone ring, thats ok
(optionally if necessary to call them to see the status then it was nice to include a senders number so that i can identify my server on the phone display when its checking the status or to play a short signal .wav in case someone takes up, so that they know what it was)

.....something like  sipsak -x 1200 -C random@ownip -s sip:adressee@hisip -vvv...
gives me "406 Not Acceptable without Contact header"
i did not try anything else yet
i already wonder if the sending call still needs to be logged in at an isp then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [OPTIONS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-11) message. The reply to an OPTIONS does two things - first, it tells you the capabilities of the remote party and second, more importantly, the Status-Code returned is the Status-Code you would get if you'd sent an INVITE.

According to [sipsak's documentation](http://sipsak.org/) you're looking for this:

```
sipsak -vv -s sip:nobody@foo.bar
```

Comment: thanks, but ....  ** reply received after 43.531 ms **
   SIP/2.0 406 Not Acceptable
   final received

Comment: And not all endpoints support OPTIONS in a way that's fully compatible with the spec, so be wary.

Comment: can you send a ping or message with `sipsak`?

Answer (score 0):

SIMPLE will work, but it may be overkill for what you want to do.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMPLE

Of course, not all SIP phones support SIMPLE.